# How to rewrite rxjs code without making calls within the subcribe method?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Hi I am having an angular 5 project and rxjs library used. i have code snippet below. I would like to rewrite in a better way.

```
 export class AccountDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
     ngOnInit() {
        this.route.paramMap
          .pipe(
            tap(paramMap => { this.id = paramMap.get('id') }),
            switchMap(paramMap =>
              forkJoin(
                this.accountsService.get(paramMap.get('id')).pipe(
                  catchError(error => {
                    this.notFoundService.checkStatus(error);
                    return _throw(error);
                  })
                ),
                this.accountsService.getAccountUsers(paramMap.get('id'))
                )
              )
            )
          .subscribe(
            ([account, users]) => {
              this.isLoading = false;
              this.account = account;
    
             let hasTransactionalReportingEnabled : boolean = this.account.features.some( feature => feature.code === FeatureCode.TRANSACTIONAL_REPORTING);
    
              if(hasTransactionalReportingEnabled) {
    
                this.accountsService.getAccountEsmeGroup(this.id).subscribe(
                   (accountEsmeGroup) => {
                     this.accountEsmeGroup = accountEsmeGroup;
                   }
                );
              }
              this.users = users;
            },
            () => {
              this.isLoading = false;
            }
          );
      }
    }
```

In the account-details.component.ts class have an ngOnInit() method. Its two http service calls using  rxjs forkJoin function namely, this.accountsService.get(paramMap.get('id')) & this.accountsService.getAccountUsers(paramMap.get('id')) . Then in the subcribe I am making another call this.accountsService.getAccountEsmeGroup(this.id), only if the variable hasTransactionalReportingEnabled expression is  true. Is there any better way to rewrite the above snippet of code in rxjs. I am not sure it is good idea to make another call in the subscribe method.

appreciate if you can help

thank you

Comment: Given the nature of your work I would suggest you ask your coworkers first, or avoid posting original code to a public website. But you are correct, you should `switchMap` after `forkJoin` and make API call within the original pipe.

Comment: i dont have cowerker . i work alone . infact this code works but i want to know is there any better that is more readable or cleaner solution to this kind of problem of making calls within a subcribe .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it becomes much easier to simplify the code if you break it up into different parts. You have essentially 5 different pieces of data: `id`, `isLoading`, `account`, `users`, `accountEsmeGroup`.

Let's start with the id.  It comes from an observable source.  It looks like you are copying to a different property (`this.id`) only to use it for other observable calls.

This isn't necessary to "tap out" this value (*or any value, most of the time*). Let's define it as an observable:

```js
  private id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => params.get('id'))
  );
```

Isn't that nice? It's clear that `id$`, if subscribed to, will emit the id.  And, if the route param value changes (*user navigates to another account*), the new id will be emitted.  Great!

Now, let's look at how we can define observables to depend each other.  Since `users` depends on the `id`, we would define like this:

```js
  private users$ = this.id$.pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.accountsService.getAccountUsers(id))
  );
```

Here `users$` will always represent the users for the account last emitted by `id$`.  [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) handles subscribing to the observable call to getAccountUsers and whenever it receives a new `id`, it will make a new call and emit that result.  Awesome!  This is reactive: if the param changes -> `id$` emits new id -> `users$` emits the new array of users.

The definition of `account$` will also begin with `id$`. It looks like `esmeGroup` could be an optional property of `account`; to assign the `esmeGroup` property, we can conditionally return `undefined` or the result of the call to `getAccountEsmeGroup()`:

```js
  private account$ = this.id$.pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.accountsService.get(id)),
    switchMap(account => {
      const hasTransactionalReportingEnabled = account.features.some(
        feature => feature.code === FeatureCode.TRANSACTIONAL_REPORTING
      );
      const esmeGroup$ = hasTransactionalReportingEnabled
        ? this.accountsService.getAccountEsmeGroup(account.id)
        : of(undefined)

      return esmeGroup$.pipe(
        map(esmeGroup => ({...account, esmeGroup}))
      );
    }),
    catchError(...)
  );
```

Now, let's combine these observables into a single view model observable that can be consumed by our template.  Instead of using [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin), we will use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest).  They are similar, but forkJoin, will only emit once, whereas combineLatest, can emit multiple times, which is nice because if our `id` url param changes, it would be nice if our data was automatically (*reactively* ) updated.

```js
  public vm$ = combineLatest([this.users$, this.account$]).pipe(
    map(([users, account]) => ({users, account}))
  );
```

**Have you noticed we haven't subscribed to anything yet?**

**Have you also noticed we haven't needed `ngOnInit` either?**

In my opinion, this makes the component controllers much simpler.

Now, in the template, you can use the [`async`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe) pipe.  I don't know what your template looks like,  but here's a simplified example:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading; else content">
  <p>loading...</p>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #content>
  <div *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of vm.users">{{ user.name }}</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>{{ vm.account.name }}</h3>
    <p *ngIf="vm.account.esmeGroup as group">{{ group.name }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

There are several ways to handle the `isLoading` value.  One simple way is to use [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) to set `isLoading = true` when `id$` emits and set `isLoading = false` when `vm$` emits.

So, altogether, a complete solution could look something like this:

```js
export class AccountDetailsComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  
  private isLoading = true;
  
  private id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => params.get('id')),
    tap(() => this.isLoading = true)
  );

  private users$ = this.id$.pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.accountsService.getAccountUsers(id))
  );

  private account$ = this.id$.pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.accountsService.get(id)),
    switchMap(account => {
      const hasTransactionalReportingEnabled = account.features.some(
        feature => feature.code === FeatureCode.TRANSACTIONAL_REPORTING
      );
      const esmeGroup$ = hasTransactionalReportingEnabled
        ? this.accountsService.getAccountEsmeGroup(account.id)
        : of(undefined);

      return esmeGroup$.pipe(
        map(esmeGroup => ({...account, esmeGroup}))
      );
    })
    catchError(...)
  );

  public vm$ = combineLatest([this.users$, this.account$]).pipe(
    map(([users, account]) => ({users, account})),
    tap(() => this.isLoading = false)
  );

}
```

In my opinion, this solution accomplishes your goal of:

> rewrite in a better way

There are several benefits:

- there are no nested subscriptions
- each piece of data is separately defined, making it easier to comprehend and make changes in the future
- the code template is reactive; if any piece of our data changes, the view will update automatically
- we expose a single observable to our view, which we can then easily consume with a single `async` pipe; alleviating the need to manage any subscriptions